# Usage of 'on the brink of'

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, speech, contemporary-english, literary-english

(Talking about a chimp): "In human age, he would have been on the brink of puberty."

I was told that this sentence is odd because 'be on the brink of' is usually used for something negative: suicides, disasters etc. Though this is most often the case, I don't think this is necessarily true. For example, you can say "on the brink of greatness".

In this particular sentence, would it be sound more natural, comparatively speaking, to use "on the threshold of puberty" instead?

-Edit-

Google Ngram Viewer makes it clear, I think: http://goo.gl/IqozD

Comment: But puberty *is* a disaster.

Answer (score 1):

According to [macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/brink):

> - the brink >> the point in time when something very bad or very good
> - is about to happen the brink >> the top of a very steep cliff

ex- Their marriage is failing. They're on the brink of divorce.

Look [here for further clarification](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57653/can-we-say-on-the-brink-of-off-topic); it has already been asked.

Comment: what do you mean by 'it has been answered' ? and can you please give an example of 'brink' being used in a positive sense? Can't find one myself.

Comment: Here is the duplicate btw : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77143/on-the-brink-verge-edge-of

Comment: @camelbrush: Can't find one? [Look harder](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min%3A1996%2Ccd_max%3A2000%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22on+the+brink+of+winning%22&oq=%22on+the+brink+of+winning%22&gs_l=serp.3...1360184.1362462.0.1362747.17.15.0.0.0.0.181.1738.0j15.15.0.ckwqrh..0.0...1.1.7.psy-ab.3OpWGZ52HaA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.eWU&biw=1483&bih=848&ech=1&psi=j2dRUd31Aoje8wSD8YCYDQ.1364289553922.3&emsg=NCSR&noj=1&ei=j2dRUd31Aoje8wSD8YCYDQ).

Comment: @J.R. That actually is a very good and very common example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Oxford Online Dict defines:

> ***[brink](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/brink?q=brink)***:
>   a point at which something, typically something unwelcome, is about to
>   happen; the verge: the country was on the brink of a constitutional
>   crisis

So, I would agree with the general form of *brink* used to suggest something *negative* mostly. And as mentioned from other people below, a good example of *verge* being used in a positive sense is *'on the verge of winning'.*

And for your sentence, you might want to use '*[verge](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/verge?q=verge) of puberty*'.

I will not recommend using *threshold* as it sounds unnatural here.

Comment: Thank you for your lucid answer. 'verge' is the perfect choice. 'cusp' would be too archaic, I guess? I still do think 'brink' can be used in positive instances, few thought they might be. An example of which can be found at http://goo.gl/h27Ni

Comment: _typically_ is the operative word. If _brink_ was **only** used to refer to something negative, the definition would read, "a point at which an unwelcome event is about to happen." I think whoever told the O.P. that the quoted use was "inappropriate" was being pedantic and overly restrictive.

Comment: @J.R. Thank you for saying that. My thoughts exactly. Unfortunately I did not have a solid basis for my opinion at the time, which is what led me to post my question here.

Comment: @Raghav "on the brink of puberty" is apparently not that unusual an expression, as you can see @ http://goo.gl/E2r92

Comment: @C, *verge* is good; have to disagree about *[threshold](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/threshold#Noun)*,  I see nothing un-natural about it

Comment: I love using the term 'in the mouth of' or 'at the mouth of', as I think it just sounds awesome. I mean 'He was at the mouth of puberty' similar to standing at the mouth of a cave or river, if you are going to travel down it, it is sure to be an journey filled with unexpected events, just like puberty!